# Inconsistency when using Sikuli to recognize text

Tags: ocr, sikuli, text-recognition, sikuli-script

I'm using Sikuli to create automated tests for an application.
Text recognition is sometimes inconsistent so I have to use screen captures instead of text.

While trying to find a solution I found out that if I obtain the text in a specific region I get it correctly but then if I try to look for that obtained text on the screen Sikuli can't find it.

One example is trying to obtain and search for the menu "Users" in a menu bar using this code:

```
myregion = Region(51,24,51,16)
texto = myregion.text()

print("FOUND TEXT:")
print(text)

find(text).highlight(3)
```

The expected result is:

- The text in the region is printed
- The text is found and highlighted on the screen

But the actual result is that the text is not found by Sikuli.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently an issue with text recognition. I've had the issue too. I've brought the issue to the author of the program and wont be fixed any time soon.